# Read attribute set id from product

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, ce-1.7.0.2

i'm trying to read the attribute set id from a product on a custom page.
So if the article belongs to attribute set named "Hose" i want to get the custom attribute gtabelle_hose. if the article belongs to the attribute set named "Rock" the custom attribute "gtabelle_rock".

At this time i'm using this code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(16);

$eavConfig = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
/* @var $eavConfig Mage_Eav_Model_Config */

$attributes = $eavConfig->getEntityAttributeCodes(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    $product
);
```

but all of my attribute sets are in the array $attributes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See this link, i will help you.[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091375/how-do-i-get-attribute-set-name

Answer (score 9):

Try this.

```
     // Get product.
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(16);

        // Get attribute set model.
        $model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');

        // Get attribute set id.
        $attributeSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();
        $attributeSet = $model->load($attributeSetId);

// This is attribute set name.
        $attributeSetName = $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName();
```

Comment: This doesn't work to :(
Maybe its my fault, i have to add this code to my phtml file, hadn't i?

Comment: @AndreS : Did you check the above code after I edited it? I tested this code. It worked. If you are sure about your code put it here. We'll check what is the issue.

Comment: This is my code. With echo i get no message and with var_dump($attributeSetName) i get NULL

How get i the code displayed like you?


`code`
`<?php
// Get product.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(16);

// Get attribute set model.
$model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');

// Get attribute set id.
$attributeSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();
$attributeSet = $model->load($attributeSetId);

// This is attribute set name.
$attributeSetName = $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName();

var_dump($attributeSetName);

$_name = $this->getProduct()->getName(); 
?>`code`

Comment: @AndreS : I tested your code. It prints `'Deafalut'`. Make sure that there is a product with id 16. Just `var_dump($product->getData())` and see.